# Terraform Apply hangs and crashes ever since force quitting a previous apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

Currently, when I try to run `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`, my code hangs for a very long time before eventually throwing this command

```
Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating provider credentials: error calling 
sts:GetCallerIdentity: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, exceeded maximum number of attempts, 25, 
https response error StatusCode: 0, RequestID: , request send failed, Post
 "https://sts.us-east-1a.amazonaws.com/": x509: “Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate” 
certificate is not trusted

│ 
│   with module.test.provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on asg-launch-configuration/provider.tf line 1, in provider "aws":
│    1: provider "aws" {
│
```

This only stared to happen after I believe a previous `terraform apply` was interrupted with a Control + C.  I have deleted all of the terraform state files (I believe) and have even deleted the entire folder where the code was, but the error persists when I try to run other `terraform apply` commands.  I have also went into the aws console and I believe deleted all the items that are provisioned by that terraform code.

Any idea what issue may have occurred?

Edit:

I am using a module, but the provider block is only this:

```
provider "aws" {
     region = var.region
}
```

Edit 2:
It turns out there was a ec2_instance_profile that had not been deleted.  I was able to change the aws region and when running `terraform apply` it told me that the above was still there, and I was able to delete it using the AWS CLI.  Now everything works as expected.

Comment: could you provide your terraform provider block code? The error is alluding to improper provider credentials & there are different ways to set your provider block, so it would be good to see what you have to help troubleshoot.

Comment: @paulg the provider block doesn't give much since I'm using a module, but I'd be happy to share any other parts that may be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was a ec2_instance_profile that had not been deleted. I was able to change the aws region and when running terraform apply it told me that the above was still there, and I was able to delete it using the AWS CLI. Now everything works as expected.